# In KendoUI JSP Servlets receive parameters as JSON

Tags: jsp, servlets, grid, kendo-ui

When defining a Grid (using JSP wrapper) my servlet receives the parameters `pageSize`, `take`, `skip` and `page` as a JSON string in the name part of the parameters. I mean, the servlet receives one single parameter which name is: {"take":10,"skip":0,"page":1,"pageSize":10} and the value is empty.

Equivalent code using JavaScript (traditional KendoUI) receives 4 parameters:

1. name: `take`, value: 10
2. name: `skip`, value: 0
3. name: `page`, value: 1
4. name: `pageSize`, value: 10

Is this difference intentional?
Is correct encoding a JSON string as the name of the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in JSP tag library: when `parameterMap` is `null` (not defined) `TransportTag.doEndTag` defines `parameterMap` as:

```
function(options,type){return JSON.stringify(options);}
```

instead of leaving it empty, preventing JavaScript `RemoteTransport.setup` (client side) from invoking `identity` function as happens for other frameworks.

Removing this extra generation in the taglib, causes JSP wrapper to generate the same HTML/JavaScript code.